# search among formerly featured questions

Tags: feature-request, bounty, search

As far as I know, there is no “been formerly attributed a bounty” tag in the search options? I tend to like featured questions even when the bounty is no longer active and such a feature would be useful for me.

Comment: A related question on meta.SO: [Is there a way to search for past bounties and their amounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122917/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-past-bounties-and-their-amounts)