# previous featured questions

Tags: discussion, bounty

Short question:

Is there a way to check all the previous featured (on bounty) questions?

The reason I ask is that I always liked the featured quesitons and find it hard to search for **past** ones. The only way I know is to look for questions with a red bounty sign.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169239/why-hasbounty-search-option-was-never-implemented

Comment: I am [not entirely sure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272653/are-all-bounty-question-tweeted-on-per-site-twitter-acounts), but I think that all (or at least moth) of the featured questions are tweeted here: https://twitter.com/StackMath

Comment: A related feature request: [search among formerly featured questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6694). Some SEDE queries are also mentioned here: [Could list of unresolved past bounties be useful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23647). And a few queries are listed also in this MathOverflow Meta post: [What would be good place to list unresolved bounties?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3539) (Do not forget to switch the sites when using the queries from there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the database:

> [Posts with bounties ordered by date and bounty](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/66672/posts-with-bounties-ordered-by-date-and-bounty)

...maybe you'll need to put `top 1200` there to get them all.

Comment: This is great. Maybe this should be a new feature? You know maybe don't delete past questions from the list featured, but mark them as awarded or something.