# Would it be a good idea to create a Bounty chatroom?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, chat

Would it be a good idea to create a chatroom for users to ask for bounties on questions (own or not)?

Say OP (user) wants/needs an answer to a question (could be their own or not).

But for some reason no one answered that question, so starting a bounty might help.

But what if OP (user) doesn't have enough points to start a bounty (less than 75 points)?

In that case, OP (user) could go to the *Bounty chatroom* and explain briefly why they would like someone to start a bounty on their (that) question and so somebody else could start a bounty on such question.

**edit**

I have created such [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103446/bounty-chatroom-). I don't know whether it's necessary or not, but just in case.

Jirky pointed out in the comments under Burt's answer "Users with less than 75 points generally don't know about meta, so you shouldn't necessarily conclude." in response to my comment "When I posted this, I thought that some users with less than 75 points or so would be supporting my idea but as we can see, none said that. Which tells me that there's no need for that chatroom"

Comment: It would have to be a good question for me to part with any rep.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Of course. Maybe their brief explanation it's not enough, you'll have to like it also :p

Comment: I think you'll find very few willing participants. minimum bounty is 50 rep. low rep users can't afford the rep change as it can change privileges, at last check, and high rep users usually haven't got there by bounty giving...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee This is not for me but for the ones who can't start bounties. As you can tell I can afford bounties.  There was a time tho when I used to have 123 points or so, now I have 1234

Comment: There used to be room called *bounty room*, but it was intended for a different purpose than what you describe. More details can be found here: [Could list of unresolved past bounties be useful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23647#23715)

Comment: There's a project along these lines that's been in the works for some time now, actually. I should have more to say about it soon.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I was actually planning on simply creating that chat room on New Year's Day, but a 3-day-trip came up, so I postponed. I will post about it in meta on Saturday when I get back home, so that you can run through the list of rules, edit and comment and whatnot.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber oh wow :) and when did you plan to say the awesome news?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so everybody was thinking about but decided to keep it a secret.. :)

Comment: well not really a secret (but hidden definitely), I have just seen @MartinSleziak's comments on CRUDE

Comment: I guess adding link to the recent post by Jyrki Lahtonen also here (in the comments) might be useful: [Launching *Pearl Dive* - a chatroom where excellent questions/answers meet willing sponsors](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31105).

Comment: @MartinSleziak i'm not sure, I haven't fully read his post

Comment: @ellisaba I certainly agree that Jyrki's post is different from yours. (In particular, it explicitly discourages users from promoting *their own* posts in the newly created room - while your posts has a different focus, which includes users' own question. Still, it is related - which is why I thought that linking to the post in comments could be useful; and that's what I've done by posting the above comment.)

Comment: maybe the chatroom should be called apo's gallery. you know i posted already 3 pics and counting lol

Answer (score 3):

Check out [The Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive) chatroom!

In this chatroom, someone who wants a bounty placed somewhere can explain why and others evaluate if they want to place a bounty.
Not only is your idea a great one, but others think so too - and created this chatroom for people like you!

Comment: :) I already did, a quick check the other day.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, some more details on this chatroom can be found in this post: [Launching *Pearl Dive* - a chatroom where excellent questions/answers meet willing sponsors](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31105).

Comment: Sir, I was thinking that how does your answer answers my question ?

Comment: @Isabellatrix - It means yes, it's a good idea and someone did it.

Comment: How would I derive a 'yes' from 

'Check out The Pearl Dive chatroom!' FYI there's no way to do that. Now, notice _that_ chatroom has very different intentions to mine

Comment: @Isabellatrix I think that someone with needs you described could find help in The Pearl Dive.

Comment: I doubt that. My idea was to include _any_ kind of questions and afaiu that chatroom only looks for _excellent posts_

Comment: Also, it seems to me that their intentions is kinda to reward excellent posts. Mine was to find a possible answer, for users that can't start bounties because they have less than 75 points

Comment: @Bellatrix I was under the impression it was for both...

Comment: @Burt I've asked about it on that chatroom, just to confirm. They haven't responded yet

Comment: @Bellatrix - It looks like they just put a bounty on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197141/do-side-rational-triangles-of-the-same-area-admit-side-rational-dissections - a question with no current answers. I think they are looking for excellent questions, but to convince someone to put a bounty on your question you would anyways need to show why it's a good question.

Comment: Exactly, how would one justify that a, say, homework question it's an excellent question? lol "It's an excellent question because professor told me so :p" // Also, notice that the question that you linked has currently 15 upvotes!!

Comment: @Burt But you know, regardless of the points of view, I think mine was not a good idea. When I posted this, I thought that some users with less than 75 points or so would be supporting my idea but as we can see, none said that. Which tells me that _there's no need_ for that chatroom

Comment: @Bellatrix Users with less than 75 points generally don't know about meta, so you shouldn't necessarily conclude. For my part I can say that it is unlikely that I would sponsor a homework question with 0 upvotes. That suggests to me that the having th question answered won't add anything new to the site. In this project I want to promote good content as opposed to catering to the needs of users.

Comment: Why don't you ask users who like to answer homework questions for help? Check out the people at the top of the weekly leagues.

Comment: @Burt told you. Check Jyrki's first comment: "For my part I can say that it is unlikely that I would sponsor a homework question with 0 upvotes. " (notice he is the creator of such room)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For your second comment: it turns out **I** don't have the need to do that, ok? maybe others do and that's what the chatroom was going to be about