# How to bump someone else's old, unanswered question that's exactly the question I want to ask?

Tags: discussion, bumping, questions

On the main site, there's an old, unanswered [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339606/continuous-function-for-day-night-with-night-being-c-times-longer-than-day) that's exactly the same question I'd like to ask. Is there some way to bump it?

And what would meta be without a meta-conversation: I've read through the answers *about bumping* here on the meta, and I see only two options for me, not being the person who asked the original question: either I could edit the question (this seems undesirable) or mention it in the appropriate chat room. This second options seems fine, as far as it goes, but it seems like a wider audience could be reached if the question could be bumped, and the wider the better, considering that no one has answered it after months.

I'm interested in anyone's thoughts.

Comment: You could offer a bounty for the question being answered as well.

Comment: Hey, I see that you already offered a bounty. For what it's worth, my thinking was "What the heck, I haven't offered many bounties. I could spend some rep on that if the question looks legit." It's a totally ad-hoc solution, but someone bothering to ask the proper way to do things on Meta stands out from the crowd, and it's the kind of behavior I'd like to encourage.

Comment: See also: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) and [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC That's an excellent and generous idea! I'm really encouraged by all the support here; your offer is like the cherry on the sundae. Many thanks to all of you!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Hey, if you're still up for something ad-hoc, I wonder if you might spend some rep on my question? The answers on the bountied question were over my  head, so I finally posted one with specifics on what I'm trying to do. I've gotten only one answer so far, and it seemed promising, but I can't figure it out. I could learn to live with the function I have, and I feel a little weird asking, but now I'm curious whether there's even a way to do what I'm trying to do. Cheers

Comment: @SaganRitual: It looks like a question has to be open for at least two days before one can put a bounty on it. I've added your new question to my bookmarks, but you can comment back to me here if I don't get around to putting the bounty on by Monday. I imagine we should properly take this conversation to the Pearl Dive chat room, but I'll confess it's not really my practice to visit there.

Comment: I'll also add that questions like yours are ones I really like: born out of a curiosity to see how to explain (or at least simulate) our observed world, and the math, while it fits the technical definition of "elementary" is still complicated enough to be interesting.

Comment: Or you can reference the question on meta, which seems to have been very successful! (Just kidding, this isn't something that should be done in general, obviously.)

Comment: In my experience, bounties never helped. I would suggest simply posting the answer again to draw attention to it if you don't have enough rep for a bounty/want to save it for other questions.

Answer (score 14):

This is exactly where [bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) are for. You have just enough reputation ([75 or more](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)) to post one. The Help Center article begins to talk about your own question, but posting a bounty on somebody else's question works just as well.

> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is non-refundable. If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty. **You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about a bounty, but I don't ever answer any questions on the math site, not being a strong math person. I don't know how I could ever recover the points. As it is, I worry that having offered a bounty once before makes me look like a problem child, having such a low reputation. I wish I could transfer some of my rep from the programming site. Cheers

Comment: It seems you've already offered a bounty before: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/182584/saganritual?tab=bounties&sort=offered thanks to the association bonus. You could help improving the grammar/formatting of existing posts in the form of suggested edits. Or ask a good novel question.

Comment: @SaganRitual Answering the MSE question bountied by you, I noticed a tab to this meta question and suggested that it is yours. Since there are a lot of questions at MSE and my possibilities are limited, I regularly look for new questions in my specialities and also for bounty questions, [not because I’m greedy for a reputation]
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387879/weak-composition-with-restrictions0-9/2391431#comment4937263_2393221), but rather to find a question for which somebody really needs an answer.

Comment: Concerning the particular question, I already found a general (polynomial) construction for $f$ and now I’m evaluating a range of $c$ which is provided by the construction.

Answer (score 12):

You can try the [pearl dive chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/102837/pearl-dive).

See also this post in meta: [Launching *Pearl Dive* - a chatroom where excellent questions/answers meet willing sponsors](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31105)

Comment: Upvoting the suggestion. It is not quite the type I had in mind, but, sure, the question is sufficiently non-standard to warrant a bit of extra attention! In other words, I like to think I would have coughed up the rep.